# How deal with CSV and text-array filed in AWS Cloudsearch?

Tags: amazon-cloudsearch

How CSV file should look when one of the field is text-array?

I have this:

docid,name,textarray,num
1,name1,"t1,t2,t3",333

but its not working, textarray became not array but string "t1,t2,t3".
I upload this file by aws console.

Another question, is possible that text-array filed became suggester field?

Answer (score 0):

This may not be possible to do using the Cloudsearch console. 
Instead, try using the **cs-import-documents** command line tool:
http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cloudsearch/latest/developerguide/import-documents-command.html

Check the `--multivalued` option to specify the multi-value fields in the CSV file.

The latest version can be downloaded from here:
http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cloudsearch/latest/developerguide/using-cloudsearch-command-line-tools.html#installing

Here's a sample CSV:

> docid,name,age,gender,pets,hobbies
>
> doc1,john,18,male,"dog,cat","surfing,riding"
>
> doc2,jane,22,female,"horse,dog","gaming,parties"

Assuming that the fields "pets" and "hobbies" are configured as text-array or literal-array, the import command will look like this:

```
cs-import-documents -d myDomain --source source.csv -mv pets,hobbies
```